# Which one should I start first rails server or sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I know this is simple question to most of you. What after googling so many sites for `sidekiq` uninitialized constant error, i found few answers. like

1. Upgrade sidekiq version.
2. Eager Load your lib or job folder.
3. use after commit.
4. Restart Sidekiq.

After doing 1 ,2 & 3 , I am little bit confused because I am still getting the error. [mperham](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) in one issue said that **Reloading is not thread-safe so Sidekiq can't use it. OTOH, Workers are designed to be very easy to TDD. If you use TDD, you'll find you don't need to restart Sidekiq much at all.**

But when I restarted sidekiq no success. I am little bit confused like should I start sidekiq first to eager load the active job class or should I start rails server and then sidekiq to eager load the active job class.

Which should I start first so that I don't get uninitialized constant error or RecordNotFound error? Thanks.

Comment: Please, show your code, it's not clear what is your problem exactly. However, usually you start sidekiq first and then your rails app, so your app may use your sidekiq workers.

Comment: Does doing this eager load my active job class?

Comment: It's hard to say exactly until you show us your exact error message, code that makes that error and your eager loading settings.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what order you start processes.  They have nothing to do with your error.

Your error is because you are trying to autoload code which does not follow the Rails naming conventions.  Code within `lib/` should be `require`d as Rails does not autoload anything in it.  Code within `app/` must follow Rails naming conventions and may be autoloaded.

Comment: I have `jobs` folder inside `app` directory. My `application.rb` contain this line `config.eager_load_paths += ["#{config.root}/app/jobs"]`. My job file in `jobs` folder looks like:

    `class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base

       queue_as :high

       def perform(*args)
        .....
       end

    end`

What is wrong with this naming convention. I am trying to call job from model using `MyJob.perform(some_arguments)`.

Comment: what's the name of the file defining MyJob?

Comment: Name of file is `my_job.rb`.

Comment: Everything in `app` is eager loaded so you shouldn't add it manually.  You use `MyJob.perform_later(args)`

Comment: Does it affect any thing if I have manually added it in application.rb? Is this the reason for `uninitialized constant` error, I am getting on my production server?

Comment: Does sidekiq in development and production behaves differently?

Comment: No but Rails may act differently based on config/environments/$rails_env.rb.